# PyCharm Matplotlib plot parametric equation with range

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I want to plot a graph in PyCharm, using Matplotlib and a parametric equation. In this equation x and y are defined by some constant variables (a, b & c) and another variable (θ) which is in a range between 0 - 10. Python doesn't seem to handle the range because it's not a string.

This is an example code with an example equation:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 2
b = 3
c = 4
θ = range(0, 10)

x = (a + b * c) / θ
y = ((a / b) + c) * θ

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I would like to have something like this (2d) and eventually 3d:

[image: Graph]

I have tried to use the for loop and updating the graph, but that resulted in a very slow PyCharm and the graph to shut down.

Does any of you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 2
b = 3
c = 4
θ = np.linspace(0, 10) #this sets an array between 0 and 10

x = (a + b * c) / θ
y = ((a / b) + c) * θ

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

For the rest as an advice: np.linspace doesn't work with math.fabs, math.cos, math.pow. You have to use np.abs, np.cos or np.power instead ;)